# PHP unset not working on files uploaded in same PHP script

Tags: php, file-upload, delete-file

I haven't had this issue for years, but this is making no sense to me... I upload a file, then I move it to AWS, then I want to delete the local file. unset() is not working, though.

First I just did it the way I do on all my similar situations:

```
$location =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$dest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/'.$filename;
move_uploaded_file($location,$dest);

//DO AWS UPLOAD STUFF//
//THEN,

if(file_exists($dest)){
   unset($dest);
}
```

However, this did not work. So I even tried to change file permissions (was 644, changed to 755) since I was going to delete immediately anyway. Just added

```
chmod($dest, 0755);
```

Right after moving the uploaded file. In both situations it does not delete the file. What am I missing?

Comment: Which user is the owner of the PHP files? (Is is the same as the webserver user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unset` just removes the in memory reference.

If you're wanting to remove the *physical* file you want [`unlink()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

So your code will be

```
$location =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$dest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/'.$filename;
move_uploaded_file($location,$dest);

//DO AWS UPLOAD STUFF//
//THEN,

if(file_exists($dest)){
   unlink($dest);
}
```

Although that doesn't seem right, as you'll be moving the file and then deleting the file you've just moved.

If you're wanting to confirm it was a move and not a copy, you'll need to change to:

```
if(file_exists($dest) && file_exists($location)){
   unlink($location);
}
```

Comment: Oh man... it's those simple things that waste so much time. Of COURSE it's unlink, I don't know why I was using unset. Thank you so much, easy fix.

Comment: To answer the "not making sense" part - I upload the file locally, then move it to AWS, then delete the local file. I just did those comments in the middle of those two things to represent the file getting put on AWS instead of putting the code for that there.